# Get value of selected radio button which is saved in Firebase, and set it as default state in user profile

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
public void showFields(){
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
    databaseReference.child(User_Login.userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            id1.setText(User_Login.userid);
            name1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
            password1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString());
            mobile1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("mobile").getValue().toString());
            city1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue().toString());
            area1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("area").getValue().toString());
             //gender.setSelected(dataSnapshot.child("area").getValue().toString());       
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

How can I set the gender radio button to its selected value from the database, as I did for the Edit Text ones.

Comment: I think u can do something like this gender.setSelected(dataSnapshot.child("area").getValue(Boolean.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code :

```
if (list.contains(dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString()){
                            int pos = list.indexOf(dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString());

                            gender.setSelection(pos);
                        }
```

Where list is arraylist set to your gender spinner adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

First, u have to store gender value string to Firebase.

gender.equalsIgnoreCase will check if the value of gender equals Man (case man), if true then the radiobutton male will setChecked(true).

```
public void showFields(){
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
databaseReference.child(User_Login.userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        id1.setText(User_Login.userid);
        name1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
        password1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString());
        mobile1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("mobile").getValue().toString());
        city1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue().toString());
        area1.setText(dataSnapshot.child("area").getValue().toString());
         String gender = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
            if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Man")){
                mGenderMan.setChecked(true);
            }else if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Woman")){
                mGenderWoman.setChecked(true);
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});}
```

Comment: It may help if you explain your answer some.  What was the problem with the OP's code?  How does this fix it?